# Do paradoxes exist due to velocity addition?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, velocity, observers

Do paradoxes exist due to velocity addition ?

..
[image]

In the above diagram, we have a very lengthy 259,627.885 km long space station.

Rocket "A" is parked at the left end of the space station. Let us assume that Rocket "B" has almost instantaneously accelerated to 259,627.885 km/s, as it departed from the right end of the space station. From the space stations point of view it is seen that it takes Rocket "B" 1 second to reach the opposite end of the space station. ( 259,627.885 km's / 259,627.885 km/s = 1 sec )

However, due to Time Dilation and Length Contraction, those on board Rocket "B" experience only 0.5 of a second, and they view the length of the space station as only 129,813.924 km's long.  Thus they see their velocity relative to the space station as 129,813.924 km's/.05 sec = 259,627.885 km/s, meaning they too see the same relative velocity as do those on board the space station.

The situation is the same for Rocket "C", with the exception of the opposite direction of travel.

In the case of Rockets "E" and "F", they see their relative velocity as being 259,627.885 km/s. This is due to each traveling at 173,085.256 km/s relative to the space station, but in opposite directions. Thus if you add 173,085.256 km/s + 173,085.256 km/s via using the Velocity Addition equation, the final result is 259,627.885 km/s, just as illustrated within the diagram.

Also, if taking into account Time Dilation and Length Contraction, those on board Rocket "E" will observe that their velocity, relative to the space station, is  173,085.256 km/s.

Now, .... taking all of this into account, those on Rocket "E" will therefore assume that Rocket "F's"  velocity relative to the space station, is the total relative velocity between the two rockets, minus their specific velocity relative to the space station. Meaning, 259,627.885 km/s - 173,085.256 km/s = 86,562.628 km/s. ( This happens to be 173,085.256 km/s divided by 2 )

Yet this produces a paradox. After all, both rockets will find themselves reaching the center of the space station at the same time, (if leaving the ends at the same time ), thus both velocities must be the same.

Can this paradox be resolved ?

( I don't know why the image is blurry ? The original is sharp.)

Comment: The velocity addition formula still applies when you perform subtraction. $w=\frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}}$. It works just as well when one or both of $u$ and $v$ are negative

Comment: It's only a paradox if you assume that they left at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that they left at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As with most apparent paradoxes in relativity, the problem is that you are neglecting to account for the [relativity of simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity)--if the rockets left at the "same time" in the frame of the station, they did *not* leave at the same time in the frame where rocket E was at rest during its journey across the station.

Say that we place the spatial origin (x=0 km) of the station's coordinate system at the left edge that rocket E departs from, and say that the rocket departed at t=0 seconds. Then if rocket F departs the right edge simultaneously in this frame, the event of rocket F departing could be assigned coordinates x=259,627.885 km, t=0 seconds. Now if we want to look at a different frame where rocket E is at rest after accelerating, we can suppose the spacetime origin of this frame is also located at the event of rocket E departing the left edge, so in this second frame which we can denote with primed coordinates, that event has coordinates x'=0 km, t'=0 s. Assuming the x axis of the station frame and the x' axis of the the primed frame are aligned, and that the rocket has a velocity v along the x-axis of the station frame, then we can use the [simplest form of the Lorentz transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Boost_in_the_x-direction) to map between these two frames:

$x^{\prime} = \gamma (x - vt)$

$t^{\prime} = \gamma (t - (vx/c^2))$

With $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$, in this case 1.22474487. Thus if the event of rocket F departing the right side has coordinates x=259,627.885 km, t=0 s in the station frame, in the primed frame this same event will have the following coordinates:

x' = 1.22474487 * (259627.885 km - (173,085.256 km/s * 0 s)) = 317977.920 km

t' = 1.22474487 * (0 s - (173,085.256 km/s * 259,627.885 km)/(299792.458 km/s)^2) = -0.612372435 s

So in the primed frame where rocket E is at rest after accelerating, at t'=-0.612372435 s rocket F accelerates away from the right end of the station at position x'=317,977.920 km and begins to move towards the spatial origin, x'=0 (where E will come to rest in this frame after accelerating at t'=0), at a velocity of 259,627.885 km/s. The time needed for rocket F to cover this distance according to this frame will be 317,977.920 km / 259,627.885 km/s = 1.22474487 s, so rocket F will reach x'=0 where rocket E is sitting at t' = -0.612372435 s + 1.22474487 s = 0.612372435 s. Meanwhile, at t'=0 s in this frame the left end of the station passes the origin and continues to move in the -x' direction at -173,085.256 km/s, so at t'= 0.612372435 s the left end will be at -173,085.256 km/s * 0.612372435 s = -105,992.64 km. And if the station is 259,627.885 km long in its own rest frame, in the primed frame it must be 259,627.885 km / 1.22474487 = 211,985.28 km long due to [length contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction), thus the distance between its left end and its midpoint is half this, or 105,992.64 km. So if the left end of the station is at x'=-105,992.64 km in this frame when rocket E is meeting rocket F, that means that the primed frame predicts that rocket E meets rocket F at the exact midpoint of the station, exactly as was predicted in the station frame.

Comment: Replace space station with long truck that is at ground rest. Truck members and those on ground see all clocks are in sync. Inside, Rockets "E" and  "F" launch at 12:00 Noon and reach center at the same time. "E" and "F" each measure their velocity relative to the truck as 173,085.256 km/s, and their velocity relative to each other as 259,627.885 km's. Accelerate truck to a high velocity then repeat launch. Inside, nothing seems any different. Only the on ground observers will notice that the clocks at the ends of the truck are no longer in sync etc. Thus the paradox inside the truck, remains.

Comment: @Sean - Why is that a "paradox"? Naturally different frames have different definition of whether two clocks are 'in sync', but the view of the truck frame is just as valid as the view of the ground frame, in relativity there is no objective frame-independent truth about simultaneity of events at diff. locations. There would only be a paradox if different frames made different predictions about frame-independent facts like what part of the station/truck the rockets will be next to when they meet, but both frames do agree they meet at the midpoint, and so would the ground frame in your example.

Comment: Rockets "E" and "F" each measure their velocity relative to the truck as 173,085.256 km/s, and their velocity relative to each other as 259,627.885 km's. Even if the truck accelerates to a high velocity, what goes on inside the truck still seems to be exactly the same if the launch is repeated. The laws of physics remain the same. Thus in both cases, Rocket "E" still deduces that Rocket "F's" velocity relative to the truck, is 86,562.628 km/s ( 86,562.628 km/s = 259,627.885 km/s - 173,085.256 km/s ) even though  those on Rocket "F" may have informed them otherwise as they passed by each other.

Comment: @Sean - You are using the phrase "F's velocity relative to the truck" in an equivocal way. 86,562.628 km/s is the ["closing speed"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#Closing_speeds) between F and the truck in E's frame, i.e. the rate the distance between F and the end of the truck is changing as measured by rulers and clocks at rest in E's frame. In relativity this is distinct from the speed of the truck in F's frame, as measured by rulers and clocks at rest in F's frame. There is no paradox in this since these are measurements of different things using different instruments.

Comment: Tell that to those on board Rockets "E" and "F". If, as they pass by each other, both choose to pass information across to the other concerning the deduced velocity of the other, meaning the others velocity relative to the truck or space station, in each case this info will not agree with their own direct assessment. Sure, they can close their eyes and just say that different frames of reference did it, but that does not resolve the puzzle that was witnessed in real time. Strip away any knowledge of SR, and they have a bit of a puzzle on their hands.

Comment: But they know they each used different rulers and clocks to make their measurements, and each one sees the other's rulers as length contracted and the other's clocks as slowed down and out of sync, why should it be a surprise they get different values? Why is this more paradoxical than the fact that, in Newtonian physics, the "velocity" of the rocket would have different values depending on whether you measure it using rulers and clocks at rest on the truck or rulers and clocks at rest on the ground?

Comment: Yes, if SR is brought into the picture, and thus they "KNOW" to look into things such as clocks slowing down and rulers being of different lengths and so forth. Otherwise, they would have no answer to the puzzle.

Comment: Even if they don't know SR in advance, if one of them uses their own rulers and clocks to *measure* the rulers and clocks of the other, they'll find that the other's rulers are shortened and the other's clocks are running slow and are out-of-sync. But sure, if they don't know SR and don't think to perform this kind of test they will find the result puzzling...I don't think this rises to the status of a genuine "paradox" though, there are all sorts of results in physics that might seem puzzling if you lack understanding of other factors that can logically explain it.